# ¿Como generar instalador de aplicación windows form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer

he desarrollado un proyecto de escritorio(windows forms) en C# usando el Visual Studio profesional 2013. Pero me gustaría saber si existe algun programa o algo que permita crear un instalador de mi proyecto. Ya que, como trabajo con Dlls, archivos .rdlc(reportviwer), tendria que copiar aparte del ejecutable los archivos que estan dentro del bin\Debug y de los rdlc para que funcione la ejecución. Yo quisiera evitar todo esto, que con solo instalar se agregue todos los componentes que se han de necesitar.

Me gustaría saber si existe algo que permite que haga todo eso, algun instalador, o generador de instalador, o lo que cumpla el objetivo.

Comment: clickonce no te sirve?

Comment: no lo he usado, lo desconosco

Comment: Te recomiendo en Other Project Types -> Visual Studio Installer -> Setup Proyect. Esto tienes que añadirlo como otro proyecto dentro de la misma solucion en la que tengas el programa al que le quieras añadir un instalador.

Comment: Yo utilizo el Inno Setup, es muy sencillo. Le indicas en un documento los ficheros que quieres incluir en el ejecutable y listo. Rápido y sencillo

Comment: @Danilo realiza actualizaciones de tu pregunta mediante la opción [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/93506/edit), no agregues nuevas respuestas para  actualizar tu situación, saludos.

Comment: te recomiendo que actualizes el visual studio si eso no sirve reinstala el visual studio y marca la casilla visual basic!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

te recomiendo que al momento de generar la aplicación compiles en modo Releace, ya que así tu código va optimizado y quita código innecesario que se necesita para realizar el debug, puede utilizar varios acercamientos para realizar el instalador, el que te recomiendo es Click Once, aquí esta el link donde hay un tutorial

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb384248.aspx

esta documentación es muy completa y te explica como funciona, con este acercamiento a desplegar una aplicación te permitirá inclusive que la misma aplicación se actualice utilizando una ruta para que se descargue e instale la última versión de tu aplicación desde un servidor en la nube si más adelante quieres quitarte el tedioso problema de ir a buscar a tu cliente para actualizar versiones mas recientes.

Para lograr que se incluyan las librerías de ReportViewer en el instalador, te vas a la pestaña de Publicar --> Archivos de aplicación como se ven en la imágenes a continuación...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después ingresas aquí...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
De esta manera incluirás las librerías para que se visualicen los reportes que creaste... espero te sirva

Comment: puse una foto de como me sale. Es diferente.